# Phonegap InAppBrowser with Header

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, iframe, inappbrowser

Is it possible to show jQuery Mobile header(header with buttons) under InAppBrowser?

I have tried with iframe like below...

```
 <div id="con" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <iframe id="iIFrame" frameborder="0" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
 </div>
```

it worked well but it is not horizontally scrolling in iPhone. 
 Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

my code and result: http://jsfiddle.net/balaguru2014/sdpYX/1/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
});
</script>
```